# Run a dev server in CI pipleine

Tags: vue.js, continuous-integration, nuxt.js, devops, github-actions

I have a CI pipeline setup using Github Action/Workflows, where i would want to run Cypress Automated tests, However I am having some logical problems of how to run my dev server. let me show you my pipeline

```
name: Nuxt CI Pipeline

on:
  push:
    branches: [ CI-pipeline ]
  # pull_request:
  #   branches: [ master ]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [ 14.x ]
        # See supported Node.js release schedule at https://nodejs.org/en/about/releases/

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      uses: actions/setup-node@v2
      with:
        node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
        cache: 'npm'
    - name: Make envfile
      uses: SpicyPizza/create-envfile@v1
      with:
        envkey_ENV: staging
        file_name: .env
    - run: npm ci
    - run: npm run dev
    - run: | 
        cd e2e
        ls -l
        npm ci
        npx cypress run
```

Now I want to spin up the devserver and run the tests on that port usually 3000 , however the problem is when the command `npm run dev` is executed, the pipeline keeps on waiting there and doesnt move forward , which makes sense as devserver doesn't return a response as other commands will , so its kinda stuck there. My knowledge of devops is bare minimum , can someone point out what am i missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the way of execution is not ideal, especially since so the node server is also not killed correctly in the end. Using a helper package like [start-server-and-test](https://www.npmjs.com/package/start-server-and-test) should do the trick for you:

```
npm install --save-dev start-server-and-test
```

While I'm not sure what exactly is behind your scripts in your `package.json`, it could look something like this in the end:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start:ci": "<<start your dev server>>",
    "cy:run": "cypress run --browser chrome --headless",
    "cy:ci": "start-server-and-test start:ci http://localhost:3000 cy:run"
  },
```

Then you can simply run this as a single command in your pipeline with `npm run cy:ci`. The script will take care of starting your dev server, waiting for the URL to be available, then executing the tests and after all tests are finished, it will shut down the server.

Comment: I wish I can give you 100 Upvotes and a beer, I've been banging my head around for days on this, thankyou so much for this, keep up the good work

Comment: I have a problem where the cypress tester could not access the dev server running on http://localhost:3000. Any idea why this happens?

Comment: Only with this information it is difficult to make a guess. I would recommend to open a new question for your issue including some implementation details. Feel free to link it here as a comment, then I can take a look.