# Cypress can't find server when checking out repo in Azure DevOps pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines, cypress

I have an Azure DevOps project that has 2 repos in it, one with the .net web app and another with Cypress tests. I need to create a pipeline that builds and runs the unit tests from the web app repo, then checkout the Cypress repo and runs the e2e tests. When my pipeline tries to run the Cypress tests, I get the error "Cypress could not verify that this server is running: https://localhost:5001/"

I believe because my cypress tests are in a different repo, I need to keep my web app running on a server until my cypress tests are completed. Is this correct? I'm not sure so this is a guess. How can I set this up so that my tests can run properly?

Here is my pipeline yaml file:

```yaml
trigger:
- development

resources:
 repositories:
   - repository: e2ecypress
     type: git
     name: devopsapp/e2ecypress

jobs:
  - job: build_unit_tests
    displayName: '.Net Build'

    pool:
      vmImage: 'windows-latest'

    variables:
      solution: '**/*.sln'
      buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
      buildConfiguration: 'Release'

    steps:
    - task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

    - task: NuGetCommand@2
      inputs:
        restoreSolution: '$(solution)'

    - task: VSBuild@1
      inputs:
        solution: '$(solution)'
        msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)"'
        platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
        configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

    - task: VSTest@2
      inputs:
        platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
        configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

  - job: cypress_tests
    displayName: 'Cypress Tests'
    pool:
      vmImage: 'windows-latest'
    
    steps:
    - checkout: e2ecypress

    - task: NodeTool@0
      inputs:
        versionSpec: '14.x'
      displayName: 'Install Node.js'
    
    - task: Npm@1
      inputs:
        command: 'install'
      displayName: 'NPM Install'
    
    - script: | 
        npx cypress run
      displayName: 'Cypress Tests'
```

Here is the error from my pipeline run:

[image]

Comment: Maybe you can have a look at my comment to your previous question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70681905/6135684

Comment: @SebastianoVierk I am currently trying that approach. Each job in a pipeline gets a fresh new virtual machine. Could this be my issue? That after my app build, it deletes the vm, and then a new one is created for cypress. Would my cypress app need to use the same vm as the .net job?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution would be to check out both repositories in the same job like:

```
steps:
  - checkout: self
  - checkout: e2ecypress
```

The keyword *self* refers to the repository you execute the pipeline from, so your web app. But be aware that when checking out multiple repositories, the directory paths for them change a bit, see Docs: [Check out multiple repositories in your pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/multi-repo-checkout?view=azure-devops)

Then you can access the content from both repositories within the same job in a VM by using the correct paths. This allows you to do a build of your web app, launch it, and then run the Cypress tests on the running app.

To start your app, run the tests, and automatically exit the web app when finished, you can use the solution described in the following answer which is also recommend by Cypress: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70541458/6135684

Comment: Thank you! this helped a lot. I added the  checkout steps, and when running commands and scripts, I had to add the directory to point to. so: workingDir: e2ecypress